# Running RVM Passenger install afk

Tags: nginx, rvm, passenger, ansible

Currently, when I rebuild Phusion Passenger with Nginx, I am running the command

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

However, I am now converting the upgrade process into an Ansible playbook. I'm wonering if it's possible to run the above command with default options so that the install completes itself without requiring me to input the usual options (Nginx + install path). I haven't found any docs explaining if this is possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. There is official documentation here on the subject: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/noninteractive_install.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Use the `--auto` and the `--auto-download` flags. Make sure to resolve and download all dependencies with apt-get.
The complete command should look something like this:

`passenger-install-nginx-module --auto --auto-download`